# Searchkick on Heroku is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, elasticsearch, searchkick

I deployed my app to heroku, add the `bonsai` addon for elasticsearch, and then I create a config var `ELASTICSEARCH_URL` with the url.

The class I am trying to index is `Product`.

I run:

```
heroku run rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Product
```

And it works fine. But then when I open the app I get an error, and I read the logs and this is what I got:

> Searchkick::InvalidQueryError ([400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"search_parse_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [created_at] in order to sort on"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query_fetch","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"products_production_20170105030153240","reason":{"type":"search_parse_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [created_at] in order to sort on"}}]},"status":400}):

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't have any Products in heroku. I created a product, then I run

```
heroku run rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Product
```

And now I got it working